# High Charts - mouse over event on any part of graph

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

The documentation for [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.events.mouseOver) mouse over event describes exactly what I'm trying to do in High Charts - fire an event "when the mouse enters the graph". However, if you look at the fiddle examples given in the documentation, the even only fires when you hover over a specific point rather than over the graph in general. This seems like needing to fire events on general graph mouse-overs would be a pretty general use case for a charting library, but I can't seem to get this behavior using any of the different events available. I also can't use jQuery hover because I need the related x label that corresponds to the mouse position. Does anyone know how I can fire events on this behavior?

For what it's worth, this is identical to the question asked on the high charts forum [here](http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=12915), which is left unanswered

Comment: Do you want a specific HighCharts element to fire when you enter the graph or a more generic command to execute? If the latter, then you just need a totally separate javascript function that responds to the onmouseover event for the highcharts object itself. See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover) for onmouseover example

Comment: @StephenH unfortunately yes. On hover I am updating other, related graphs based on the x value being hovered over.

Comment: So just to be clear, you do have values of x that you want to correspond to events? For instance, if I'm hovered over a datapoint where x=3, that will cause an event to occur. If I'm hovered over datapoint x=4, that will cause a different event?

Comment: I need to have the values of x, which is why I can't use something outside of High Charts. Your example is correct - I'm moving a plot line on other charts based on the x values being hovered over (at any y value, not just the y value of that specific data point). Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Have you looked at the example for [mouseover with sticky tracking](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-mouseover-sticky/)? This looks like it would be more helpful for you. The only thing is you have to mouseover the series first.

Comment: See custom event plugin http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand completely but I think you want to able to hover anywhere in the plot and determine the x,y coordinate of your hover?

If that is so, you can do this outside of `Highcharts` event handling:

```
$('#container').mousemove(function(e){ //mouseover on container div   
    var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
    var xaxis = chart.xAxis[0];
    var yaxis = chart.yAxis[0];
    xaxis.removePlotLine('plot-line-x');
    yaxis.removePlotLine('plot-line-y');
    var x = xaxis.toValue(e.offsetX, false); // find X coor where mouse is
    var y = yaxis.toValue(e.offsetY, false); // find y coor where mouse is
    xaxis.addPlotLine({
        value: x,
        color: 'red',
        width: 2,
        id: 'plot-line-x'
    });
    yaxis.addPlotLine({
        value: y,
        color: 'red',
        width: 2,
        id: 'plot-line-y'
    });
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/683Nd/).

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question right, you can use [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-mouseover/) to help you out. It essentially shows the currently hovered data in the highcharts element interacting with items outside of the chart. I've made a slight modification to the example to demonstrate how to essentially 'export' the highcharts data to a regular Javascript function where you can then call other functions and change certain global variables to affect your other elements.

I added the following function...

```
function doSomething(x)
{
    alert(x);
}
```

And changed the following code...

```
mouseOver: function() {
    $reporting.html('x: '+ this.x +', y: '+ this.y);
}
```

To this...

```
mouseOver: function() {
    doSomething(this.x);
    //$reporting.html('x: '+ this.x +', y: '+ this.y);
}
```

You can find my modified example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ShXMg/) and [here is the api reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.select) for the data points. You might also find the 'select' event helpful for your application. [Here is another example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sjw7Y/) that uses 'select'. The only difference besides changing the event function is adding the property `allowPointSelect: true,`